# iOS changing SVG textpath class to [object SVGAnimatedString]

Tags: javascript, ios, debugging, svg, safari

I have a class on my SVG textpath and use this to for javascript and css targeting. This is working fine across most browsers but on iOS Safari and Chrome the class gets removed and replaced with [object SVGAnimatedString].

My code:

```
<svg class="svg" width="200px" height="160px" viewBox="0 0 200 160" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.1">';
    <defs><path id="arc" d="M 0,120 A 90,90 0 0,1 200,120"></path></defs>
    <g text-anchor="middle">
        <text><textPath id="textpath" class="my-class" xlink:href="#arc" startOffset="50%">  <!-- Text --></textPath></text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

iOS output

```
<svg class="svg" width="200px" height="160px" viewBox="0 0 200 160" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.1">';
    <defs><path id="arc" d="M 0,120 A 90,90 0 0,1 200,120"></path></defs>
    <g text-anchor="middle">
        <text><textPath id="textpath" class="[object SVGAnimatedString]" xlink:href="#arc" startOffset="50%">  <!-- Text --></textPath></text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

It's only the class on the textpath that changes and it's done before any of the javascript takes place.

Firstly - Is there a way to prevent iOS from doing this and do I want to prevent the default behaviour?

Secondly - Why does it do this? I can sort of understand if it adds a class but removing all other classes seems overkill

Thanks

Comment: This is the underlying data type for the field. If you show your code we might be able to suggest a workaround. Reporting it as a webkit/chrome bug is probably the right way to go though.

Comment: I've added in my code examples and the output from iOS